# Cannot get/post data in Firefox

Tags: node.js, post, firefox, port, block

I use following code to post data to database

```
router.post('/insert',async(req,res)=>{
const data =new model({
    name: 'GLX SHAHIN 3',//req.body.name,
    price: 7100000,//req.body.price,
    count: 5//req.body.count
})
try{
    const save= await data.save();
    res.status(200).json(save);
    Console.log('inserted.');
}
catch(err){
res.status(404).json({message: err.message});
}});
```

whenever I enter localhost:8080/insert in browser, I get this error:

`cannot get /insert`

and Firefox console say:

`Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico (“default-src”).`

Comment: Standard request for Browsers is "GET" not "POST". If you enter `localhost:8080/insert` in the adress bar and hit enter, the browser performs a GET request. Ignore the "favicon.ico" request, the browser trys by default to fetch a favicon for the page.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make request to an endpoint from browser, it will send a GET request by default. Since your route is `router.post()` not `router.get()` you get the error `can not get/insert`

If you want to test your endpoint for POST, you will have to use application like [postman](https://www.postman.com/).

If you are daring enough you can also use [cURL](https://curl.se/)